# iOS Passbook - Is it possible to read auxiliaryFields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, passbook

Using the iOS Passbook framework, you can read `userInfo`, and the documentation says you can read "common data" without it stating what it means by "common".

What I'd like to know is whether using iOS Passbook - Is it possible to read the `auxiliaryFields`?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

You have to do this:

`po [pass localizedValueForFieldKey:@"a2"]`

Where `a2` is the name of the key you want to access, given that:

`{"key":"a2","value":"Super sale!","label":"Code","textAlignment":"PKTextAlignmentLeft"}]`

Thanks

This is now resolved